# How can I show Recyclerview cardview with horizontal views like adds after every four items in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am developing E Commerce app. In my app I needs to show items in grid view manner. But i needs to show one horizontal item (like add)after every four items in grid view manner using recyclerview card view. adds means I am not using google add mob. I am just show an item like a add in horizontal manner. I am confused. any one can help me.

[image: Screen shot here]

Comment: i think you should use RecyclerView With CardView for hint see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30596078/4146722

Comment: Thank you for replying @PratikTank. But I needs to show every 5th item as horizontal view. I updated my question. please see my snap shot once. Thank you.

Comment: this may help you @vinodh kumar see: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

Comment: Thank you for replying Nilesh. Finally I solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
            glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    if (position % 5 == 4) {
                        return 4;
                    } else {
                        return 2;
                    }
        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
```

Comment: Hi @Dhanumjay. I followed your code. getting error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.scitus.cityskype, PID: 32698
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.scitus.cityskype.cityskypefragments.OneFragment.

Comment: are you using fragment or activity?

Comment: Previously I used Code : recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));

Comment: I am using Fragment boss

Comment: did you changed the id of recyclerview of what you have declared in your layout?

Comment: My code :   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);

Comment: In My Layout I declared recyclerview id name is :   card_recycler_view

Comment: Thank you boss it works. Thank's a lot you save my time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recyclerview or Gridview with sticky headers

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.tonicartos</groupId>
  <artifactId>stickygridheaders</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/DWorkS/AStickyHeader

http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/

https://github.com/ShamylZakariya/StickyHeaders

https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

you can use **StaggeredGridLayoutManager**

```
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager;
gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

for more information follow this link [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

[image]